# MySQL Variable Substitution

Tags: mysql, sql, parameters, dynamic-sql

I want to simplify the following using dynamic SQL like one could do in Transact SQL.

I want to do something like:

```
SET @s = replace(field_name, '_complete','')
```

and use @s instead of replace(field_name, '_complete','')

Please adive if possible and if so how.

My current code:

```
 select distinct    
if(instr(replace(field_name, '_complete',''),'_') <= 5
          ,left(replace(field_name, '_complete','')
               ,instr(replace(field_name, '_complete',''),'_') - 1
              )  
          ,replace(field_name, '_complete','')    
        ) AS form_id   ,replace(
        if(instr(replace(field_name, '_complete',''),'_') <= 5,
            mid(replace(field_name, '_complete',''),
                instr(replace(field_name, '_complete',''),'_') + 1,
                length(replace(field_name, '_complete','')) - instr(replace(field_name, '_complete',''),'_')
               )
            ,replace(field_name, '_complete','')
          ),
        '_',
        ' ') as form_name     ,field_name     from redcap_extract2use    where field_name like '%_complete'   order by 1;
```

The above would then be replaced with:

```
select distinct 
  if(instr(@s,'_') <= 5 ,left(@s,instr(@s,'_') - 1),@s ) AS form_id
  ,replace( if(instr(@s,'_') <= 5,
        mid(@s,instr(@s,'_') + 1,length(@s) - instr(@s,'_')),@s), '_',  ' ') as form_name  
  ,field_name  
  from redcap_extract2use 
  where field_name like '%_complete'
  order by 1;
```

and I would have an execute... to run the query

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly then you would want to use the [PREPARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html) and the [EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execute.html) statements.

For example:

```
SET @s = replace(field_name, '_complete','');

PREPARE mystatement FROM
SELECT DISTINCT ...... ;

EXECUTE mystatement;
```